# Why does Reminders seem to be syncing with the network, even though I have reminders turned off in iCloud settings?

Tags: ios, icloud, performance, reminders

I started using Reminders.app as soon as I got iOS 5.0, and for me it mostly works very well. As soon as I got an iCloud account, of course I turned reminder syncing on there as well.

However I soon found that reminder syncing is still quite buggy at this stage. In particular, it doesn't seem to handle moving to-do items from list to list very well. I often got duplicate items and had other problems. (Note: This is not the topic of my question.)

So I finally decided to live without reminder syncing, and just use Reminders.app on my iPhone only. I turned off reminder syncing in iCloud. This did solve the problem with duplicate items, and I'm mostly happy with it.

But... I noticed that Reminders.app **still seems to be accessing the network**, even though I haven't configured reminders to sync with *anything*. (I am basing this observation on the little spinner in the status bar at the top of the iPhone screen.)

And whenever it does this, some of the old problems come back -- mostly sluggishness and jerky scrolling, etc.

I have verified that when I put the iPhone into airplane mode, the problem doesn't happen.

Does anyone know why Reminders.app would still try to access the network when iCloud syncing is turned off? What is it trying to do? Any way to turn it off completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and turn off Reminders under the following setting pages and see if it helps:

> **Settings** > **Cellular** under *Use cellular data for:* (will be a long list)

Might have nothing to do with Reminders trying to connect to the internet, but it's worth a shot:

> **Settings** > **Notification Center** under *Today view:*

Comment: Great! This option wasn’t available when I wrote this question, but now it is. I’ll give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Locations Services > Reminders > Off

If this is on, it'll be periodically checking your location, having nothing to do with iCloud.

Comment: That didn't do it. I turned off the location services for Reminders as you suggested, but it still shows the spinner and slows performance. (Besides, I don't have any location reminders set right now.)

Comment: do those reminders contain any links, urls?